# Replacement Triac

Tags: triac, dimmer, thyristor, bidirectional

I have a simple dimmer module with a busted Triac MAC97A6. I want to replace that component so that the module will work again but stores near my area don't have that specific component. One store keeper suggested I replace it with a BT169D which he had.

Will this work out? I had a quick look at the datasheet and the parameters almost match.

Thanks in advance

Update: Links to datasheets and circuit diagram of dimmer module

[MAC97A6 Datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/MAC97-D.PDF)

[BT169D Datasheet](https://lib.chipdip.ru/140/DOC000140142.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Please link the datasheets and any datasheet or other information about the dimmer module.

Comment: Updated with required info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proposed replacement is 25x more sensitive with regard to trigger current in the relevant quadrants.  Current rating is probably okay. Voltage rating is similar (and not very generous for 220V mains).

The big problem is that one is a triac and the other is an SCR, so no the proposed part is not a suitable replacement!

Comment: Can I use a [BT136-600](https://www.promelec.ru/pdf/BT136-600-NXP.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You should replace it by a Z0107MA, a 1A, 600V, four quadrant triac in TO-92 package. It is a standard product you can find both from ST and NXP.